# How to fix html tags(which is missing the <open> & <close> tags) with HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack

I have an html with `<div><h1> hello Hi</div> <div>hi </p></div>`

Required Output : `<div><h1> hello </h1></div> <div><p>hi </p></div>`

Using HTML agility pack is it possible to fix this kind of similar issues with missing closing and opening tags?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The library isn't intelligent enough to create the opening `p` where you put it, but it's intelligent enough to create the missing `h1`. And in general, it creates valid HTML always, but not always the one you would expect.

So this code:

```
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(yourhtml);
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

will dump this:

```
<div><h1> hello Hi</h1></div> <div>hi <p></div>
```

Which is not what you want, but is valid HTML.
You can also add a little trick like this:

```
        HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.Load(yourhtml);
        doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

that will dump this:

```
<div><h1> hello Hi</h1></div> <div>hi <p></p></div>
```

Comment: its just not <p> node. In general I'm looking for a fix which will take care of the all the missing opening tags. Is there any way to that?

Comment: The library fixes all broken tags automatically, but like I say, it may not be the way you want. Difficult to say more with a so general question.

Comment: OK sounds grt, Thanks!Can you tell me how to save the out put into a string instead of Console.Out...

Comment: doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml contains the full document as text.

Comment: I maybe a bit late joining this conversation, but is there a way to turn off automatically fixing broken tags? I don't want it (I'm proxying and the client side is breaking when corrected), but I'm thinking that HAP won't work with bad html.

Comment: @tim_barber_7BB: Yeah, pretty much. A lot of what you do (eg asking for childnodes) doesn't work if there is not a well defined structure. If there is invalid HTML it needs to do something to it for it to be able to make sense of it and then it gives that back to you. I suspect after some manipulations putting back in those broken bits would be nigh on impossible (and so very rarely needed it wouldn't be worth the effort).

Answer (score 13):

When doing
`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.LoadHTML(yourhtml)` HTMLAgilityPack will automatically fix the tags for you, and then you can access those tags using: `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.OuterHTML`