# Fix missing HTML Tags using htmlagility pack

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

my input contain

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
<tr><td class="header">A
<td class="header">B
<td class="header"><b>C</b>
</tr>
</table>
```

the required output is

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
<tr><td class="header">A</td>
<td class="header">B</td>
<td class="header"><b>C</b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried the following reference

[How to fix html tags(which is missing the <open> & <close> tags) with HTMLAgilityPack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396699/how-to-fix-html-tagswhich-is-missing-the-open-close-tags-with-htmlagilit)

the output i got

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
<tr><td class="header"></td>A
<td class="header"></td>B
<td class="header"></td><b>C</b>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am new to this HTML files...

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Html Agility Pack has a special option available as a property on the `HtmlDocument` class, named `OptionFixNestedTags` for fixing this kind of HTML errors:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
        doc.Load(YourFile);

        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
```

This will output:

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="100%">
<tr><td class="header">A
</td><td class="header">B
</td><td class="header"><b>C</b>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: but how do you get the result as a string? (with printing on the console)

Comment: @alwaysVBNET - something like `doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`.

Comment: it's weird because this doesn't work:  `<p><div>1</div>`  but this will work  `<div>1</div><p>` meaning that the latter will close the `<p>`

Comment: @alwaysVBNET - nested tags is not about all html tag errors, only about li, tr, th, td. p has special treatment because (for historic an compat reasons) browsers supports loose html definition (we're talking 20 years back here). You fix some p issue with this `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["p"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;` in the beginning of your code, but there's no magic, it cannot now where to put the closing p. Otherwise ask another question.