# Parsing tags which are not closed from web page with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse the list of stations from the NOAA web site (weather.noaa.gov). If you look at the source of a page such as [Belarus Stations](http://weather.noaa.gov/weather/BY_cc.html), you can see the list of available stations is presented as:

```
<select name="cccc">
    <option selected>Select a location
    <OPTION VALUE="UMBB"> Brest
    <OPTION VALUE="UMGG"> Gomel'
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMG"> Grodno
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMM"> Loshitsa / Minsk International 1
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMS"> Minsk
    <OPTION VALUE="UMII"> Vitebsk
</select>
```

You can see that the 'OPTION' tags are not closed. The default options in HtmlAgilityPack closes the tags like so:

```
<select name="cccc">
    <option selected>Select a location
    <OPTION VALUE="UMBB"> Brest
    <OPTION VALUE="UMGG"> Gomel'
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMG"> Grodno
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMM"> Loshitsa / Minsk International 1
    <OPTION VALUE="UMMS"> Minsk
    <OPTION VALUE="UMII"> Vitebsk
    </OPTION></OPTION></OPTION></OPTION></OPTION></OPTION></OPTION>
</select>
```

Which makes it a pain to parse or traverse. I came up with the following method to recurse each  tag, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way, perhaps using LINQ?

My method:

```
private static void GetStations(HtmlNode node, ref Dictionary<string, string> stations)
{
    // the HTML is malformed, such that the <option> elements are
    // not properly closed, so we have to parse manually
    string name = node.GetAttributeValue("value", string.Empty).Trim();
    string value = node.InnerHtml.Substring(0, node.InnerHtml.IndexOf("\n")).Trim();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) &&
             name.Length == 4 &&
            char.IsUpper(name[0]))
    {
        stations.Add(name, value);
    }
    // due to not closing the <option> elements
    // we have to recurse into child nodes until
    // we get them all
    if (node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        GetStations(node.LastChild, ref stations);
    }
}
```

Which is called like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sites = new Dictionary<string, string>();
...
foreach (HtmlNode option in select.ChildNodes)
{
    if ((option.Name == "option") && (option.HasAttributes))
    {
        GetStations(option, ref sites);
    }
}
```

I feel like I am using a brute force method to get the list of stations, and I might be missing some of the power of the HtmlAgilityPack library. Is there a better way? Are there settings that might make this a non-issue? Can LINQ handle this more easily?

I am trying XPATH, as it seems the simplest mechanism to get a subset of tags. However, due to the tags not being closed, I am getting every option tag on the page, while I only want the ones inside the 'select' tag. So, one qualifier, as you can see, is that the 'option' tags I want have a @value='XXXX' where 'XXXX' is a 4-character, upper case station id. Is there a way to specify that I want only the option tags in the documente that have an attribute named 'value' with an uppercase 4-character value? Can I pass in a comparison function to an xpath statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the pointers. I did more searches for xpath syntax, and found this that works:

```
//select[@name='cccc']/descendant::option[@value]
```

this gives me all the 'option' tags under the 'select' tag with an attribute @name='cccc' where the 'option tag has a @value attribute.

Much less work than what I was doing. Now to refactor all my other code that loops through the DOM using HAP and see how XPATH can make my life easier!

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered such an issue, but unless I'm mistaken the following should pull out all option tags regardless of them being nested by mistake:

```
var optionNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Select("//option");
```

Now if there were other option tags that you didn't want, that might be slightly more difficult. But if by chance these were the only option tags that had a value containing "um" you could use `//option[contains(@value, \"UM\")]` which should narrow it to just those option tags.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAgilityPack can automatically fix closing tag but maybe [not exactly the way you expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396699/how-to-fix-html-tagswhich-is-missing-the-open-close-tags-with-htmlagilit) :

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["option"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Anyway at this point you can still select text that is supposed to be within `<option>` tag using XPath `following-sibling::text()[1]`, for example :

```
var optionTexts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@name='cccc']/option/following-sibling::text()[1]");
foreach (HtmlNode node in optionTexts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```