C# How to inject missing TR & TD in html data
I have a html where high chance that any number of TR & TD could be missing into html data.
i am looking for a routine which would inject Table, TR & TD tag if any missing.

my objective is to add/inject missing any opening & closing Table, TR & TD tag in html.
after sanitize html each row (TR) must have same number of TD tag. so want to could max number of TD and if any row(TR) has lesser number of TD tag then add empty  tag in the beginning of that TR tag.

This way i tried to inject missing TR & TD tag but no luck. any can help me.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string htmldata = @"<table>
              <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
              </tr>
              
                Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico
              </tr>
            </table>";

            string abc = AddMissingHtmlTags(htmldata);
        }

public static string AddMissingHtmlTags(string htmlData)
{
    // Define regular expressions for table, tr, and td tags
    Regex tableRegex = new Regex(@"<table[^>]*>.*?</table>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Regex trRegex = new Regex(@"<tr[^>]*>.*?</tr>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Regex tdRegex = new Regex(@"<td[^>]*>.*?</td>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    // Match all table elements in the HTML
    MatchCollection tableMatches = tableRegex.Matches(htmlData);

    foreach (Match tableMatch in tableMatches)
    {
        string tableHtml = tableMatch.Value;

        // Match all tr elements within the table
        MatchCollection trMatches = trRegex.Matches(tableHtml);

        foreach (Match trMatch in trMatches)
        {
            string trHtml = trMatch.Value;

            // If there are no td elements within the tr, add one
            if (!tdRegex.IsMatch(trHtml))
            {
                string newTd = "<td></td>";
                string modifiedTr = trHtml.Insert(trHtml.Length - 5, newTd); // Insert new td before the closing </tr> tag
                htmlData = htmlData.Replace(trHtml, modifiedTr);
            }
        }

        // If there are no tr elements within the table, add one
        if (!trRegex.IsMatch(tableHtml))
        {
            string newTr = "<tr><td></td></tr>";
            string modifiedTable = tableHtml.Insert(tableHtml.Length - 8, newTr); // Insert new tr before the closing </table> tag
            htmlData = htmlData.Replace(tableHtml, modifiedTable);
        }
    }

    return htmlData;
}

Tried with html agility pack but no luck
public static string AddMissingHtmlTags(string htmlData)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlData);

    // Ensure there is a <table> element
    if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table") == null)
    {
        HtmlNode tableNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<table></table>");
        doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(tableNode);
    }

    // Add missing <tr> and <td> tags
    foreach (HtmlNode rowNode in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr"))
    {
        if (rowNode.SelectNodes("td") == null)
        {
            HtmlNode tdNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>");
            rowNode.AppendChild(tdNode);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode cellNode in rowNode.SelectNodes("td"))
            {
                if (cellNode.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    cellNode.InnerHtml = "&nbsp;"; // Add non-breaking space if <td> is empty
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}


Have you tried "HTML Agility Pack"? What are the results?

HtmlNode.CreateNode("<td></td>")? I thought it works like HtmlNode.CreateNode("td"), but it has been years since I used HtmlAgilityPack, so I could be wrong.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397864/14171304

If you look around this site enough you should be able to find enough examples to dissuade you from trying to mix Regex and HTML parsing.

HTML Agility Pack should tell you where parsing errors are; https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773343/4139809 https://documentation.help/HtmlAgilityPack/e144ac5f-cc86-e50c-4a2f-b53ce148f0fb.htm which you might be able to use to insert missing start / end tags, before then looking for bad tr/td nesting. But are you solving the wrong problem here? Where are you getting this bad html from?
