C# How to inject missing opening TR & TD tag in html data
I am jostling for few day to inject missing TR & TD tags in my html programmatically.
from this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18397864/14171304 i found that HtmlAgility pack does this job but i saw HtmlAgility pack adding missing closing tag but it can not add missing opening tag.
This is my sample code.
string htmlData = @"<table>
           <tr>
             <th>Company</th>
             <th>Contact</th>
             <th>Country</th>
           </tr>

           Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
           <td>Maria Anders</td>
           <td>Germany
           </tr>
           <tr>
             <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
             <td>Francisco Chang</td>
             <td>Mexico
           </tr>
         </table>";

// Load the HTML into an HtmlDocument object
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
//doc.OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
doc.LoadHtml(htmlData);
string correctedHtml = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

it is my request to all that please help me to build a routine which can inject missing opening & closing both tag in my html. my html may have missing opening & closing Table,TR & TD tag.
looking for help. Thanks
